# What to do when GMap Satellite imagery is unavailable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, satellite-image

is it possible to programmatically detect with the google maps api (javascript, v2) when satellite imagery is unavailable at a certain zoom level? I am creating some maps automatically and setting them to a certain zoom level, but in a few cases there is no satellite imagery available at that level, in which case I'd like to automatically back up a zoom level. Does the api expose some way of determining this lack of imagery?

So far the only thing I can think of is trying to find out, with javascript, whether or not the image requests that the api makes are failing, and then reacting based on those failed image requests, but I can't really get it to work... and it seems a little inelegant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently trying to use? I'm researching your issue now, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you're currently trying as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind! Looks like the fix is easy: [getMaxZoomAtLatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMapType.getMaxZoomAtLatLng)

Comment: Excellent! You should flag this as the accepted answer to this question so other people who have similiar issues can be helped! I personally found this to be quite helpful. +1